# Wrong type object for key serialNumbers in response dictionary. Expected NSArray but found __NSCFString

Tags: php, json, passbook

i have a web service set up for passbook the error log is logging this error:

Get serial #s task (for device 88a9cbef8e318f61, pass type pass.com.passbook, last updated (null); with web service url https://) encountered error: Server response was malformed (Wrong type object for key serialNumbers in response dictionary. Expected NSArray but found __NSCFString.)

the code in PHP when is not found :

```
 $updatable_passes_payload['lastUpdated'] = '';
            $updatable_passes_payload['serialNumbers'] = '';
            sendResponse(204, json_encode($updatable_passes_payload), 'text/json');
```

when is found:

```
 $update_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $updatable_passes_payload['lastUpdated'] = $update_time;
            $updatable_passes_payload['serialNumbers'] = json_encode($types);
            sendResponse(200, json_encode($updatable_passes_payload), 'text/json');
```

the web service json :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: Identity
Content-Type: text/json
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.22
Server: Apache mod_fcgid/2.3.10-dev
Date: Sun, 01 Dec 2013 23:25:08 GMT

{"lastUpdated":"2013-12-01 23:25:09","serialNumbers":"[\"102058742\"]"}


i checked this json in a json validator online it returns OK
```

when is not found it returns

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/json
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.22
Server: Apache mod_fcgid/2.3.10-dev
Date: Sun, 01 Dec 2013 23:35:17 GMT
```

for some reason is not returning any json when not found

any help will be appreciated

Comment: According to spec [Passbook Web Service Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PassKit_WebService/WebService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011988-CH0-SW2) `serialNumbers` should be an array of strings, so in your example it should be `"{..., "serialNumbers": ["102058742"] }"`. 
When there are no matching passes, returning HTTP 204 with no content the correct behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is with your JSON array.  You have encapsulated your array in quotes so it is being interpreted as a string.

The following should work:

```
{"lastUpdated":"2013-12-01 23:25:09","serialNumbers":["102058742"]}
```